# Updating the react state/component correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make my component reactive on updates. I am using `componentDidUpdate()` to check if the components prop state has changed, then if it has it is has I need the `getPosts()` function to be called and the `postCount` to update if that prop is changed.

```
export default class JsonFeed extends React.Component<IJsonFeedProps, IJsonFeedState> {

  // Props & state needed for the component
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      description: this.props.description,
      posts: [],
      isLoading: true,
      jsonUrl: this.props.jsonUrl,
      postCount: this.props.postCount,
      errors: null,
      error: null
    };
  }

  // This function runs when a prop choice has been updated
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    if (this.state !== this.state) {
      this.getPosts();
      // something else ????
    }
  }

  // This function runs when component is first renderd
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  // Grabs the posts from the json url
  public getPosts() {
    axios
      .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + this.props.jsonUrl)
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(post => ({
          id: `${post.Id}`,
          name: `${post.Name}`,
          summary: `${post.Summary}`,
          url: `${post.AbsoluteUrl}`
        }))
      )
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({
          posts,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
    // We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

Comment: `this.state !== this.state` this looks wrong

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop, getProps sets the state and will update the component causing componentDidUpdate to call getProps again. So you're lucky that the condition is never true.

Comment: The condition in componentDidUpdate, `this.state !== this.state`, can never be true.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps can be used as well

Comment: Do you want to fetch data when `jsonUrl` from props changes?

Comment: try componentDidUpdate(prevState){}

Comment: @HMR yes I do, or if the post count changes which is used like this:  posts.slice(0, postCount).map(post => { in the render method of the component.

Comment: @MonicaAcha You should not use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) use [getDerivedStateFromProps](getDerivedStateFromProps) instead.

Comment: @BennKingy You don't need to fetch data again when post count changes since it is not used in getPosts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change **componentDidUpdate** to:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      this.getPosts();
    }
  }
```

This won't be an infinite loop as the getPosts() function sets state loading to false;

Now every time you need an update you just need to set your state loading to true.

If what you want to do is load everytime the **jsonUrl** updates then you need something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.jsonUrl!== this.props.jsonUrl) {
         this.getPosts();
      }
}
```

Also I don't get why you expose your components state by making componentDidMount public.

Comment: This works great! :TY: I was just removing console errors, but yeah I will change to protected. React noob but getting there!

Comment: Always happy to help!

Comment: Using getDerivedStateFromProps would be a bit simpler since you don't need to duplicate calling getPost in componentDidMount, just don't set state.jsonUrl in constructor and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your getPosts to receive the jsonUrl argument and add the following function to your class:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if(props.jsonUrl!==state.jsonUrl){
    //pass jsonUrl to getPosts
    this.getPosts(props.jsonUrl);
    return {
      ...state,
      jsonUrl:props.jsonUrl
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

You can get rid of the componentDidUpdate function.

You can also remove the getPosts from didmount if you don't set state jsonUrl in the constructor.

Comment: I will do some research on 'getDerivedStateFromProps' and implement this, this looks good TY!

Comment: @BennKingy You can also remove the getPosts from didmount if you don't set state jsonUrl in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // This function runs when a prop choice has been updated
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
   // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
   if (prevState.jsonUrl !== this.state.jsonUrl) {
     this.getPosts();
     // something else ????
    }
   }
```

this way you have to match with the updated state

Comment: That will only cause an infinite loop

Comment: No, only need to get post when json url changes. lenght is used in render and does not affect the data, only how much data is shown. When you change that state the component is re rendered anyway.

Comment: change the  state posts variable to jsonUrl

Comment: Almost there, instead try: `prevProps.jsonUrl!==this.props.jsonUrl`. Howeer; getDerivedStateFromProps would be simpler and does not require getting data in componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState){
if(prevState.loading!==this.state.loading){
//do Something
    this.getPosts();

}}
```

Comment: Again; infinite loop

Comment: try to useEffect

Comment: It's a class component, hooks can only be used in functional components.